# Any library for implementing the scrollable photo wall like Google Stories?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, polymer, google-photos

I found [Google Stories](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/6029803?hl=en) looks attractive. ([example](https://plus.google.com/+anilsabharwal/stories/e39549b6-120c-3653-b456-2457c19f8e56?authkey=1iJx3GJh))

I was just wondering whether there is any open source library (or component) I can use to implement a demo (the scrollable photo wall, optimized for touch screen) like Google Stories.

Does anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found JInvertScroll to be very easy to implement.  It is a Javascript API, and allows for side scrolling with the mouse wheel, as appears in your example.  See:

[JInvertScroll](http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/)